# Decrease bootstrap table width, colspan not working

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, html-table, bootstrap-table

I am working with a bootstrap table, which contains in the right corner a table with rowspan = "2", then it has 2 rows, and then at the other end another rowspan = "2", looking like this:
[image: imagen de tabla]

The problem I'm having is that I can't "shrink" the width of the table where the image is, that is, the first column, I tried with col-1, with colspan = "1" but so far I can't find a solution, could you help me ?, the TOTAL WIDTH OF THE TABLE WHERE THE IMAGE IS, SHOULD BE THE SAME ROWSPAN = "1".

This is the code:

```
<tr>
    <td rowspan="2" colspan="1">
  <img src="IMAGE">
      

    </td>
    <td class="col-10">
    PRODUCT NAME
    </td>
  <td rowspan="2" colspan="1">$PRICE</td>
    
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
    <span>DESCRIPCION</strong></span>
    </td>
  </tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need a set width for image row, you can use `width="...px"` into `<td width="..px">`

 **I try make a example like this**

```css
table {
      border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    table,
    tr,
    th,
    td {
      border: 1px solid #000;
    }

    th {
      padding: 1ex;
      background: #ccc;
    }
    td {
      padding: 1ex;
    }
    .divide td {
      border-top: 3px solid;
    }
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
  <td rowspan="2" colspan="1" width="200px">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ef/Stack_Overflow_icon.svg/768px-Stack_Overflow_icon.svg.png" width="50px">
  </td>
  <td class="col-10">
  PRODUCT NAME
  </td>
  <td rowspan="2" colspan="1">$PRICE</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
    <span>DESCRIPCION</strong></span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table>
<tr>
  <td rowspan="2" colspan="1" width="150px">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ef/Stack_Overflow_icon.svg/768px-Stack_Overflow_icon.svg.png" width="50px">
  </td>
  <td class="col-10">
  PRODUCT NAME
  </td>
  <td rowspan="2" colspan="1">$PRICE</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
    <span>DESCRIPCION</strong></span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table>
<tr>
  <td rowspan="2" colspan="1" width="100px">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ef/Stack_Overflow_icon.svg/768px-Stack_Overflow_icon.svg.png" width="50px">
  </td>
  <td class="col-10">
  PRODUCT NAME
  </td>
  <td rowspan="2" colspan="1">$PRICE</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
    <span>DESCRIPCION</strong></span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br>
<br>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>head</th>
        <th>title</th>
        <th>title</th>
        <th>title</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox">
        </td>
        <td>content</td>
        <td>content</td>
        <td>content</td>
        <td rowspan="2">white</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4">
            lorem ipsum
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="divide">
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox">
        </td>
        <td>content</td>
        <td>content</td>
        <td>content</td>
        <td rowspan="2">gray</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4">
            lorem ipsum
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="divide">
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox">
        </td>
        <td>content</td>
        <td>content</td>
        <td>content</td>
        <td>white</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="divide">
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox">
        </td>
        <td>content</td>
        <td>content</td>
        <td>content</td>
        <td rowspan="2">gray</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4">
            lorem ipsum
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Yes now! I solved it with your code, thank you very much. The problem is that I was creating dynamic content in the table, then it crashed, but, your code worked 100%